# Export Google App engine databases to excel files

Tags: database, excel, google-app-engine, export

I am using google app engine to store information to a small database (I have 3 tables). I would like to export these tables to excel files for data analysis. How is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

Could do with some more information before being able to give a good answer to this.

Code for Java AppEngine and Python AppEngine is obviously different (and now Go is supported too) - so which language?

There are two options:

1. Code your own specific version of an export tool depending on your requirements
2. Use the built-in download/upload tools provided see : http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html

The second option will generally be quicker to get setup, but may not do everything you want/need.

Comment: I use python for appengine coding